# How should I model for the data set to predict the y_test value?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Model modifications are being made to adjust the model's predictions in the desired direction, but there are difficulties.

**Dataset decription**

Train/ validation/ Test set

(1) X_train: (6000,4) shape

(2) y_train: (6000,4) shape

(3) X_validation: (2000,4) shape

(4) y_validation: (2000,4) shape

(5) X_test: (2000,4) shape

(6) y_test: (2000,4) shape

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT8EM.png)

The prediction results want to be, for example, (1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0).

```
from numpy import array
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import sys
import argparse
import time
import pandas as pd

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min',verbose=1,patience = 10)

X_train, y_train, X_valid, y_valid, X_test, y_test, tr_set_size = loaddata(filename)

**model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(46, activation='relu')) # relu 
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4))**

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss ='mse', metrics=['accuracy']) #mse

hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose= 1, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), callbacks= es)

result = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
print(prediction)
```

Comment: Can you please describe the problem? i.e. what is being calculated/displayed/error message and what do you want instead? It would also help to show the code for your function `loaddata` and a small subset of the data in filename so that we can reproduce your problem and better help.

Comment: Please do **not** repost verbatim questions

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `activation='softmax'` on the last layer of your NN model, so it returns probability for each classes that having the sum of probability for all classes = 1. So, the last layer will be:

```py
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

Then you can tweak the values of that by changing the max value into 1 and the rest of array to 0 by the code below:

```py
prediction = (prediction == prediction.max(axis=1)[:,None]).astype(int)
print(prediction)
```

Instead of giving the full predictions, you can just get the indices that gives highest probability by using:

```py
n = 2 # Define how many classes that having highest probability you want to take
pred = np.argsort(-prediction)[:n]
```

It will give the result of indices that having highest probability sorted from highest probability to lowest one.

Comment: **Additional Questions**

If y_train, y_validation, y_test values are not looking for one value, but for example, [1,0,0,1] and [0,0,1,1] values that are indexed to the highest and minimum X values, 
how should the model be modified?

Comment: The model doesn't need to be modified. I have added one more code block to get the indices having highest probability and it's sorted according to the probability from highest to lowest one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would like your output to be a one hot vector of classes - in which case you are looking to use argmax over your outputs. However, argmax is not a differentiable function which is why softmax is often used. You need to use a [Softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/softmax) activation function for the final layer of your network.

For example

```
    model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(46, activation='relu')) # relu 
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

And assuming it is a classifier, your loss function should reflect that. Given your example of labels, I would suggest categorical crossentropy.

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss ='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

You can then construct one-hot vectors for your predictions using

```
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
out = tf.one_hot(np.argmax(prediction, axis=1), depth=4).numpy()
```

Comment: **Additional Questions**

If y_train, y_validation, y_test values are not looking for one value, but for example, [1,0,0,1] and [0,0,1,1] values that are indexed to the highest and minimum X values, 
how should the model be modified?